# coloring table cell descendants

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am doing this on my own personal browser, viewing a pbulic website. as such, I can't change their html. I am using chrome, and stylebot to apply the CSS style. I need a CSS solution to the following:

```
<tr class="bg_small_yellow">
  <td class="row1" valign="middle" align="center" width="20">                                 
    <img class="icon_folder" src="/eaforum/images/transp.gif" alt="">
  </td>
  <td class="row1" width="100%">
    <span class="topictitle">
      <a href="/eaforum/posts/list/9578017.page" id="topic_link_9578017" title="SimCity Traffic">
        SimCity Traffic
      </a>
    </span>
  </td>
```

How can I apply `color: gray;` to the `<a>` link if and only if the `<img>` is class `.icon_folder` ?

Here is a jsFiddle page to play with. I want a solution only in the CSS pane. http://jsfiddle.net/hZr9b/

I am looking for something like this, but that actually works:

`(td > img.icon_folder) + td a:link { color: gray; }`

Comment: Can you provide the link of the website that you are looking at??

Comment: CSS? not going to happen unless you can change the HTML.

Comment: Nathan, the browser is the one I am currently on! :)

Comment: Nathan Lee, sure, it is EA Game's general discussion for a game. This one particularly: http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/categories/show/232.page

Comment: Zenith, if you can post an answer that references sections of actual specifications and offers a convincing argument, that would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the markup cannot be changed, then it is not possible using only CSS because the image and anchor aren't siblings, and there is [**no parent selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) in CSS2/3 to help navigate between these two elements.

If they were siblings, it could be as easy as this:

**HTML:**

```
<img class="icon_folder" src="/eaforum/images/transp.gif" alt="">
<a href="/eaforum/posts/list/9578017.page" id="topic_link_9578017" title="SimCity Traffic">SimCity Traffic</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
img[class="icon_folder"] + a {
    color:grey;
}
```

But as you mentioned you cannot change the markup in this instance, unfortunately you'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: thanks :) shame I can't do it but maybe I can use this to demonstrate to them why they should make a change.